# Itemize with a dash "-" instead of a bullet

Tags: lists, itemize

If I use

```
\begin{itemize}
\item asdasd
\item dsfsdf
\end{itemize}
```

the items are with a bullet, but how can I itemize these two with a "-" (a dash / a hyphen / a small line)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I had the same issue, but I had a silly mistake. **\end{itemize}** was missing on one of the earlier pages.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

One-at-a-time method:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[--] asdasd
\item[--] dsfsdf
\end{itemize}
```

---

Set all first-level bullet-point to `--`:

At preamble, in plain-TeX

```
\def\labelitemi{--}
```

or in LaTeX

```
\renewcommand\labelitemi{---}
```

These have the same effect, but if you want all your definitions to look similar you can prefer one over the other.

---

Set the first-level bullet-point to `--` only in one itemize environment:

```
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
\item asdasd
\item dsfsdf
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Note that there's no reason that it would have to be two dashes instead of one; this would work equally well as `\item[-]`.

Comment: @Tyler: `-` (hyphen) is shorter than `--` (en-dash).

Comment: @Tyler except that it is poorer typographical style, I believe.

Comment: @Vasily I would not say "poorer"; it's a **poor** style (it's a thing you want to do when you want to look like MSWord).

Comment: @picco's answer is what's needed here, I'd say.

Comment: much better looking results are obtained if one uses 
\item[$-$]
instead of 
\item[--]

Comment: @kennytm. Does the command `\renewcommand\labelitemi{---}
` available in beamer as well? I'm getting error for missing command.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for second-level bullet points?

Answer (score 74):

For reference, here's a package-wise approach using the (de-facto) list manipulation package, [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={--}]
\item asdasd
\item dsfsdf
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also set defaults with `\setlist[⟨names⟩,⟨levels⟩]{⟨keys/values⟩}`. See the [enumitem documentation](https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem/blob/master/enumitem.pdf). I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67081120/6664252) that gives some settings I like in a beamer presentation.

Answer (score 37):

```
% before \begin{document}
\usepackage{enumerate}

% after \begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[-]
 \item asdasd
 \item dsfdsf
\end{enumerate}
```

Ideally, the `enumerate` package is already in MiKTeX so you need not download it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can format code using the `{}` button in the edit window or by indenting the code by four blank spaces.

Comment: @picco: `enumerate` is a latex “required” package; a distribution that _doesn't_ contain it is non-conforming.  so idealism _ought_ not to be required...

Comment: This totally looks like an up-to-date best practice to me.

Comment: This is clearly the best answer!

Answer (score 12):

The alternative solution for whole document/representation:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=10pt, label={--}}
```

Comment: Use `\setlist[itemize]{...}`. The command `\setitemize`was deprecated 8 years ago.

Comment: Thanks. I changed.

Answer (score 7):

A much better looking results are obtained if one uses math minus symbol instead of en-dash:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[$-$] asdasd
\item[$-$] dsfsdf
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use package `enumitem` with parameter `shortlabels`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Remember use ``shortlabels'' parameter
\begin{itemize}[-]
    \item aaa 
    \item bbb
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

To use bold dash, replace `[-]` by `[\textbf{-}]`; or longer dash, replace `[-]` by `[--]`. To use `+`, replace `[-]` by `[+]`.