# How can I define bullet style for itemize with french option babel?

Tags: lists, babel, itemize, french

I would like to use `itemize` environment with the bullet style before each item. I found out that the `french` option with the `babel` package seems to define the dash style for the `itemize` environment. It is not even possible to "overwrite" this definition in the preamble as it is suggested in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62497/31058).

Here is my MWE for you to play around with it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\def\labelitemi{$\bullet$}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Blabla
\item Bloblo
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I can think of some ways to redefine the `itemize` environment in the preamble to produce the bullet even if the `french` option is loaded but would you have any "simple" solution to fix this problem without having to redefine the `itemize` environment?

Remark: I haven't tried with other options but this problem might not be limited to the `french` option.

Comment: You can use `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\bullet$}}`.

Comment: Don't forget to ping the users via @GonzaloMedina ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `french` module for `babel` you can use

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\labelitemi{$\bullet$}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\AtBeginDocument{\def\labelitemi{$\bullet$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Blabla
\item Bloblo
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Using the `frenchle` module, the author suggests in the documentation the use of `\frlabelitems` to make the redefinition; however, the execution has also to be delayed with `\AtBeginDocument` (I couldn't find any reference to this fact in the documentation?):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchle]{babel}

\AtBeginDocument{\frlabelitems{\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}%
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{**}%
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{***}%
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{****}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Blabla
\item Bloblo
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Using the `frenchb` module for `babel`, you can redefine `\FrenchLabelItem` in the preamble (notice, however, that given the settings in `frenchb.ldf`, this change will be applied to all four levels of an itemized list):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\renewcommand*{\FrenchLabelItem}{$\bullet$}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Blabla
\item Bloblo
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: btw: What is the difference between using \AtBeginDocument or just \def or \renewcommand in the preamble?

Comment: @LudovicC. `\AtBeginDocument` delays execution to a latter time than most preamble instructions.

Answer (score 3):

If I may raise this question from death... Here is another solution. Just add this to your preamble.

```
\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}
```

This will prevent babel from customizing the item labels. The things that babel customize are actually very configurable and well documented.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it does not work correctly: labelitemii are poorly indented with this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Celelibi posted, [here](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/frenchb.pdf) is a PDF that sums up various setups for french language.

The dafault behavior of: `\usepackage[french]{babel}` is to change the default layout settings to adapt to French (first paragraph indentation, the default items in itemize environment are set to ‘—’ instead of ‘•’ and vertical spacing is removed etc...).

With the following command you can override this behavior and use a custom one or even restore the default one:

```
\frenchsetup{options}
```

For instance this one restore the default behavior:

```
\frenchsetup{StandardLayout = true}
```